# Correlation matrix within a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I have the following dataframe

```
      product_id.       averageDemand
 0     655                 7.591781
 1     132                 7.565753
....           .....            ....
1261   1095               0.035616
```

My goal is to plot a correlation matrix between the products_id regarding the average demand. (so where x is the correlation as in the table below)

```
so the get: 
          655       132   .....   1261
     655   1         x     x        x
     132   x         1     x        x  
    ....     
        .....       x     x         x
    1261    x       x     x         1
```

Can someone help me how to get a correlation matrix within a column of a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `corr` in pandas like this :

```
df['product_id'].corr(df['averageDemand'])
```

Comment: hey maikel he want to plot not show

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.  However, the output is only 1 value instead of the correlation matrix. Do you know how i can get this?